# SQL database on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to provision SQL database on IBM Bluemix and I get the following error:

Service broker error: {"description"=>"Error 502 received from broker url https://csbs01-prod.mybluemix.net/sqldb/v2/service_instances}

has anyone faced a similar error ?

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: I am not sure what other information I can provide... I have an IBM bluemix account, and I am trying to create a service called SQL database. I am using the free account of Bluemix, and trying Premium plan.  As soon as I request the service I get the error mentioned above. I have done this before and usually creating the service works fine.Thanks for your time on this. Appreciate your help, if you have any specific question that can help me understand this better, please feel free to let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: Based on : https://status.ng.bluemix.net , SQLDB may be experiencing issues. Please watch out for updates on the status page.

Answer (score 0):

As reported on the [Bluemix Status Page](https://status.ng.bluemix.net) the issues with SQLDB Premium service provisioning should now be fixed. You should now be able to provision a new service instance.